# Remove character from string in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, informatica-powerexchange

I have the following string values .

string 1 = test123
string 2 = stri567

now i need to remove 123,567 from the string. which means i need only first four character from the strings.(test,stri)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reg replace to replace all numbers from a string -

```
REG_REPLACE( inp_col, '[0-9]','')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need first four characters from the column then use `substring`

```
SUBSTR(column_name, 0, 4)
```

Please make sure that you need first four digits or just strings from the columns.
In case if you need strings from the values, please use Koushik Roy's solution